# Compactness of $A \subset l^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

I'm wondering about how to approach something like this:

Let $c \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, $A = \{x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) : |x(n)| \le |c(n)|, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Show that $A$ is compact in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Should I invoke Tichonov theorem?

Comment: One technique would be to show that any sequence in $A$ has a convergent (with respect to the $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ norm) subsequence. For $r\geq 0$, let $rB$ denote the set of scalars $z$ with $|z|\leq r$.    Then $$A=\prod_{n=1}^\infty |c(n)|B.$$  By Tychnoff's theorem, any sequence in $A$ has a subsequence which converges in the product topology. It would then suffice to show that this subsequence also converges to the same limit in the norm topology.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Asserting that $A$ is compact is equivalent ot asserting that it is both complete and totally bounded. But, since $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is complete and $A$ is closed, it is clear that it is complete. So, all that remains to be proved is that it is totally bounded.

Comment: Can I ask you how to show that $A$ is closed? Sorry for the trivial question but I still have to practice with this stuff.

Comment: For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\pi_k\bigl((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr)=x_k$. Then $\pi_k$ is continuous and therefore ${\pi_k}^{-1}\bigl([-\lvert c(k)\rvert,\lvert c(k)\rvert]\bigr)$ is a closed set. Therefore, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}{\pi_n}^{-1}\bigl([-\lvert c(n)\rvert,\lvert c(n)\rvert]\bigr)$ is closed too. But this set is $A$.